# Percent of spiral galaxies in universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, galaxies

I want to know wich is the % of the galaxies with stable orbits (I think this are only Spiral ones).

cheers.

Comment: All galaxies are approximately stable, even elliptical ones. If you're just asking what percentage of galaxies are elliptical then I imagine the answer can be easily Googled.

Comment: I think that the true answer might have a fair degree of uncertainty due to uncertainty in the number of small dim dwarf galaxies that orbit the big bright ones (that are easily observable).

Comment: @John...I'm looking for the percentage of spiral ones and cant find it.                               I'm interested in galaxies where PLANETS can have stable orbits. Sorry if u understand about the galaxy orbit.  Cheers.

Comment: Why do you think that stable planetary orbits exist only in spiral galaxies? ... Did you try googling your question? The answer is easily found.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks for reply.      I tried but dont found an answer.can you send me the source you have about it?  The idea of "only spiral galaxy can have planets with stable orbits and no crashing themselves" is from documental on tv.  cheers

Comment: Hi @sammygerbil I found this:

Comment: Hi @sammygerbil I found this: http://www.konkyo.org/English/DoesLifeExistOnAnyOtherPlanetInTheUniverseAnotherLookAtSETI   check  "The Right Kind of Galaxy". Maybe I was looking for very specific kind of galaxies.

Comment: The sources and figures provided by chaz327 are the ones I found by googling your title. The konkyo article quotes 6%, which is significantly different. However, whether it is 6% or 77% is an insignificant difference compared with the other estimates made in the calculation of how many planets there are in the galaxy or universe which could support life. ... You asked about the orbital stability of planets, but this is not the same as asking if they could support life.

Comment: Hi @sammygerbil,  thanks again for ur fast replies!  I think I remember bad the idea about orbits (I saw it years ago) so maybe i'm wrong about it: so please forget it :)       what do u think about the number of 6% about galaxies that can have habitable planets?   cheers.

Comment: My opinion is irrelevant. The konkyo article was (presumably) written by an expert, which I am not. It provides an estimated probability of $10^{-20}$ for life being found **anyhere in the universe**. This is inconsistent with the estimate of 6% of **galaxies** having habitable planets. The article says that 6% of galaxies are spiral, not that 6% of galaxies contain habitable planets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are asking what percentage are spiral galaxies; the answer depends on the source, 60% per wiki; space.com says 77% or says 70%'nearby.'

Comment: can you cite the source that wikipedia cites?

Comment: Hi @chaz327 thanks for reply. I saw on documental about "barred spiral galaxy" as our is just the 2% of the global galaxies. In different places I saw different numbers, so this is why i'm doing a question here.